# Получить ссылки со страницы

Tags: c#, html, htmlagilitypack

Есть переменная в которой DOM страницы. Как с помошью HtmlAgilityPack получить все ссылки которые видны на странице?

Comment: А как выглядят эти "видные ссылки"? HTML то увидеть можно?

Comment: Например "споллер", встречается на форумах очень часто. Ссылка как бы есть, но под споллером она не видна.

Comment: Мне это нечего не дает. Спойлеры бывают совершенно разные, какие то скрывают контент полностью (выводя что то по типу "наберите N репутации") - такие не как вам не получить. Другие просто свернуты стилем - обычно это div блок с неким стилем, тут все просто - берете сам div и затем все его внутренние ссылки. Найдите пример такого HTML и тогда вам скорей всего помогут!

Answer (score 2):

Видимые - никак. Видимость может стилизоваться с помощю таблиц CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ ищется в гугле :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```

Comment: На сколько я понял, этот вариант найдет все ссылки, а необходимо только те, что отображаются. Сейчас не могу проверить.

Comment: Тоест ссылка может быть спрятанна и надо проверять атрибуты типа width !=0

Comment: @Dr. link это объект класса HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode , в котором есть поле string OuterHtml . Так вот там есть все атрибуты

Comment: @Dr. Вот пример https://dotnetfiddle.net/pl4aOs